# Hibernate save function does update instead of insert using spring mvc

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

In my case, there are two tables.
Both the tables are joined with Username. Username being the primary key in Login Table and Foreign Key in Customer Table.

I want to insert data in those two tables using hibernate save function. When I first run the server and click on save button, it inserts the data without any problem to both the tables. On sending the same request to the server again, it inserts the data in the Login table but it updates the Customer table with the with new data instead of inserting.

I am not sure whats going wrong here...

```
@Component  
@Entity  
@Table(name="login")  
public class Login implements Serializable {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   

//  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="login_id")
    private BigInteger loginId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="login_username")
    private String loginUsername;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="login" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private Customer customer;
}

@Component   
@Entity   
//@Scope(value="request")   
@Table(name="customer")   
public class Customer implements Serializable {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* Define all the columns of Customer Table */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private BigInteger customerId;

     @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="customer_username",referencedColumnName="login_username")
     private Login login;
}
```

Comment: You should also post the code that handles the request and does the save.

Comment: I hope the comment on the @Id annotation is for the sake of testing, I would not encourage this approach though.